# Log is not loading in to new catalina.out file

Tags: apache, tomcat, fedora, pentaho

we are using tomcat server to our application . Here very much log creating into catalina.out . we want to make  archive of catalina.out . then deleted old catalina.out file . and created a new catalina.out file and given permissions .

But the new log is not loading in to catalina.out file .

After restarting tomcat server , it started to load log in to catalina.out file .

But ,We want achieve this with out down time .

Thanks,
Srinivas

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Tomcat Logging either with JULI or Log4j. 
Take a look at some configuration [examples](http://www.mulesoft.com/tomcat-logging).

If you choose to use log4j with Tomcat, pay attention to these configuration attributes

```
#  Max file size, after which the logfile is rolled and indexed
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=10MB

# Number of backup indexed log files.
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=10
```

In [Apache Log4j Extras](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/extras/index.html) you can find log file appenders that support archiving.

Comment: i dont have lo4j.properties file , we have log.properties and log4j.xml  in tomcat of pentaho

Comment: you can always create log4.properties by hand and pass it to java from the command line using the arguments -Dlog4j.configuration=file:<filepath>. You give no information what's this "log.properties", it's good that you have it, but I have no idea what's inside it. Good luck anyways!